# Get ids of checked check boxes in a form using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table- each row has a checkbox of name  checkBoxDelete. The id of the check box is unique(used the customer id).
I would like to get all the unique ids that were selected. So, I started by gathering all the elements of the form. Then check if it is a checkbox that is checked. If it is ,then get it's id.

```
var elLength = document.deleteForm.elements.length;
for (var i=0; i<elLength; i++){
    var type = deleteForm.elements[i].type;
    if (type=="checkbox" && deleteForm.elements[i].checked){

    var rowID=deleteForm.elements[i].id;
    checkedIds += rowID + ";" ;
    count++;   
    }
 }
```

However, rowID is always ";". 
I believe I am not getting a reference to the checkbox correctly.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `var rowID=deleteForm.elements[i].id;` to `var rowID= document.deleteForm.elements[i].id;`

You forgot `document` before selecting `deleteForm`

Comment: @Mary no problem.  Always helpful for someone to look at a problem with a fresh set of eyes